bluetooth service do not connect ubuntu 22.04
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 installed bluez package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluetooth:
 bluetooth depends on bluez; however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
 bluetooth
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


This question is similar to: Package dbus is not configured yet. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
